# React - Update data in the parent component after a change in child component

Tags: reactjs

I started to learn React and after reading a the docs and a few tutorials I decided to build a basic todo application. The data is provided by mockapi.io. Right now I have two components, `List` which is responsible for getting and displaying the data and `Item` which represents a single todo item.

So here's my question: how can I update the parent component to show a completed or deleted item without refeching the entire data set?

I mean I could call the `fetchData()` method after `completeTask()` or `deleteTask()` but I'm feeling that it's not the way to do it. Probably things would be easier with Redux, but I'm not there yet in the learning path.

List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Item from './Item';
import { API_URL } from './config';

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            error: null                
        }

        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData() {
        axios.get(`${API_URL}/todos`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    items: response.data
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({
                    error: 'Error while fetching data.'
                });
            });
        }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }   

    render() {
        const { items, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{error}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="list-container">
                {items.map((item) => (                                        
                    <Item current={item} key={item.id} />                    
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Item.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from './config';

class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            item: props.current,
            error: null
        }
    }

    completeTask(id) {
        axios.put(`${API_URL}/todos/${id}`, { 
            completed: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Error while updating data.'
            });
        });
    }

    deleteTask(id) {
        axios.delete(`${API_URL}/todos/${id}`, { 
            completed: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Error while deleting data.'
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const  { item, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{error}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (                                                    
            <div className="list-item" key={item.id}>
                <p>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{item.title}</span> 
                    <br />                             
                    {!item.completed && <button onClick={() => this.completeTask(item.id)}>Complete</button>}                            
                    <button onClick={() => this.deleteTask(item.id)}>Delete</button>
                </p>
            </div>                                    
        );
    }
}

Item.propTypes = {
    current: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why are you create a component for each item even though you can do it in the same file and save some performance

Comment: How do you want this change reflected in the parent component?

Comment: @Liam Creating a component for item is definitely the react way to do it.

Comment: @Liam, becuase this is what's described as the best practice.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings, for example, when a user clicks the `Complete` button I want the item to have the strikethrough styling and persist the change in the database, but don't fetch the entire data set afterwards.

Comment: @Cosmin That sounds like something you can perform in the child component itself, removing an item would require parent intervention.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings, I thought about that and it would work for the `completed` property, but what about the deletion?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings & Cosmin, Yes but if we think programmatically I guess it's better if we could use a small code gives the same thing instead of repeating same functions and more same codes for each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the parent component, we would pass in a prop function:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Item from './Item';
import { API_URL } from './config';

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            error: null                
        }

        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData() {
        axios.get(`${API_URL}/todos`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    items: response.data
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({
                    error: 'Error while fetching data.'
                });
            });
        }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    deleteItem(id) {
        this.setState(prevState=>{
            const newItems = prevState.items.filter((item)=>item.id!==id);
            return {
                items: newItems
            }
        })
    }   

    render() {
        const { items, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{error}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="list-container">
                {items.map((item) => (                                        
                    <Item current={item} key={item.id} deleteItem={this.deleteItem} />                    
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

In the child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from './config';

class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            item: props.current,
            error: null
        }
    }

    completeTask(id) {
        axios.put(`${API_URL}/todos/${id}`, { 
            completed: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Error while updating data.'
            });
        });
    }

    deleteTask(id) {
        axios.delete(`${API_URL}/todos/${id}`, { 
            completed: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.props.deleteItem(id);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Error while deleting data.'
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const  { item, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{error}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (                                                    
            <div className="list-item" key={item.id}>
                <p>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{item.title}</span> 
                    <br />                             
                    {!item.completed && <button onClick={() => this.completeTask(item.id)}>Complete</button>}                            
                    <button onClick={() => this.deleteTask(item.id)}>Delete</button>
                </p>
            </div>                                    
        );
    }
}

Item.propTypes = {
    current: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

We are using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the item with the ID from the state defined in the parent component, so that the UI re-renders.

Comment: Thank you for the deleting logic. Works like a charm, but please update the post with `prevState.items.filter` instead of `prevState`. Maybe somebody else will need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback from the parent to the child, and in the callback, based on the child's id, update the state.